# Rotating iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, rotation

I found out that rotation makes my app crash.

When you hold the device in your hand, you move it a bit and app registers all of those tiny movements, changing orientation accordingly, and it looks as app's busy. Everything slows down.

Also, when I scroll something and simultaneously change orientation, scrolling stops.

How can this things be managed?

EDIT:

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation) {
   if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.FaceUp ||
       UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.FaceDown) 
   {
      return false; 
   } else { 
      return true; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Post code for your ViewController, in particular "shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation" method.

Comment: public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
  {
   if(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.FaceUp || UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.FaceDown)
   {
    return false;
   }
   else
   {
    return true;
   }
  }

Comment: in the future just edit your own post with the code formatted. Is this MonoTouch?

Comment: I realized that when I don't change orientation, I never get memory warning. Everything works smoothly.

I tried stop listening to changes when views are not visible, but same thing kept on going on.

Comment: Sorry for the code. Yes, it's Monotouch. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use MonoTouch so I can't tell you if that's the case. The code there seems fine, so I can't think of why that would be a problem. I've edited your post, and tagged as MonoTouch hopefully someone will be able to help you out.

Comment: While I do not believe this code is causing your problem, it is wrong. The ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method is called every time there is a change in the X,Y axes alone. Your implementation will never return false, since the method will not be called when the device orientation changes from eg. Portrait to FaceDown. In short, you have to check the parameter passed to it for *interface* orientations, instead of *device* orientations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That bit of code is not causing your crash, it looks fine.  You need to run with the debugger and find out where the exception is and then figure out why it gets an exception.  Otherwise we are just guessing in the dark.

Comment: It crashes randomly. I get memory warning and after some time it just crashes. I have a memory leak somewhere, but can't find it.

Comment: @Mr Q - When it crashes, is it due to memory exhaustion or something else?  What appears in the console when your application crashes?  When you run it under the debugger, where does it halt?  What is the stack trace?  These are all questions that you'll need to answer before we can help you here.  Just saying "it crashes" tells us nothing.

Comment: Thank you guys. Anyway, the question was not well formed. I mean, I still need to resolve why my frame rate drops when rotating the device, but the most important thing is that I found why it had been crashing. It was due to memory exhaustion. First of all, I disposed all image objects after using them to instantly release memory. After that, I went through code and found some variables declared locally. After taking them to class scope, apparently references remain.